# Best way to search in all columns in Phalcon ORM?

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

Always I use this following code in mysql:

```
    SELECT * FROM myobject 
WHERE MATCH(`name`, `foo`, `bar`) AGAINST ('$search') IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

In Phalcon ORM:

```
 myobject::find([
            "columns” => "id, name”,
            "conditions" => "name LIKE ?1 OR foo LIKE ?1 OR bar LIKE ?1 ",
            "bind"       => [1 =>$search]
            ]);
```

How to find through all columns?

Is this possible in Phalcon ORM in a quick way?

Comment: Hey, there is no such ready solution since Phalcon aims for top performance. However there is a nice solution from the community: https://github.com/stanislav-web/Searcher Note: I haven't used it, but looked through source files and it looks promising. Also here is a nice list of Phalcon goodies: https://github.com/sergeyklay/awesome-phalcon

Comment: @NikiMihaylov you are Active in Stackowerflow AND phalcon forum together :)

Comment: Spreading Phalcon love. More people should know about this awesome framework :)

Comment: yes! php is my life , And Now phalcon is my Love,I will translate Phalcon Docs to my language too:)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by @niki_mihaylov, there is no ready solution available in Phalcon. You can however just grab all your model's columns and add a `where` clause for each column.

Depending on how many columns your table has and what kind of thing you are searching for, there might be a drop in performance.

[controller]

```
$result = myobject::searchColumns($search);
```

[model]

```
public static function searchColumns($search)
{
    $query = self::query();

    foreach (self::columnMap() as $column) {
        $query->orWhere($column . ' LIKE :search:');
    }

    $query->bind(['search' => '%' . $search . '%']);
    return $query->execute();
 }
```

The `self::columnMap()` refers to the `columnMap` defined in your model. A better solution might be to define a custom array with all the columns you would like to search through. Hereby limiting the amount of searchable columns and possibly an increase in performance.